# Variable values not storing

Tags: c, variables

I needed to create a program for my C programming class that will allow the user an unknown amount of numerical inputs. It will then take those values and find the minimum, maximum, and average.

Below is the source code I have written thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//Post-Lab #4
int main()
{
    int sums = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int number;
    int min = number; //Lines 6 to 12 define the variables being used in this program.
    int max = number;
    int avg;
    char confirm = 'Y'; //Using this to end the while loop under user influence.

printf("NOTE: Program will continue to receive inputs until user states 'N'. \n");//a negative value ends the while loop.
printf("Please enter a value: ");
scanf(" %d", &number);
printf(" %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", number, min, max, n, sums);//Im using these print command to troubleshoot what the values look like after a step.

while (number >= 0) //Utilizing while loop to allow user multiple, in this case, numerical inputs.
    {
    printf("Would you like to enter another value (Y/N): ");
    scanf(" %c", &confirm);

    if(confirm == 'Y') //Had to nest another if statement. Program was including negative value.
       {
        printf("Please enter a value: "); //Prints guide for user.
        scanf(" %d", &number); //Used to read user inputs

        n = n + 1; //Counter to use for finding the average later in the program.
        sums = sums + number; //Since this program cannot use arrays, these values will not be stored, but simply added.

        if (number > max) //If statement used to determine the maximum   value as the user enters them.
            {
            max = number;
            }
        if (number < min)
            {
            min = number;
            }
        printf(" %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", number, min, max, n, sums);
       }
       else
        break;
    }

avg = sums / n; //Calculates the average.

printf("Your results are: \n");
printf("The maximum value is: %d \n", max); //Lines 41 to 44 simply print        the results of the calculation.
printf("The minimum value is: %d \n", min);
printf("The average is: %d \n", avg);

return 0;
}
```

My problem is happening from lines 8 to 17.
When I `scanf` for a user input on line 16 it sets the `number` variable to just that, but does not set the variables `max` and `min` to that input.
 It just equals to `2686868`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `scanf`. How do you know it was successful? If it doesn't return the number of expected variables to assign, then those variables are not assigned.

Comment: You set `min` and `max = number` before you input any value to `number`. So the program has *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Seems to be working as expected. You need to set `number`, `min`, and `max` _after_ the user inputs data. You seem to be thinking any changes to `number` will propagate to `min` and `max`, but they will not.

Comment: @Jonothon I used the last 'printf' statement (line 17) to see what values are collected after the 'scanf' is executed.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider then the current values will be forgotten. They sould be declared as `int min = INT_MAX; int max = INT_MIN;` also `#include <limits.h>`.

Comment: There are no current values at the first `scanf`...

Comment: @WeatherVane My previous versions included defining `int number = 0;` but then `min = 0` so any data will be skewed simply because its already at its minimum. Then no matter what the user enters the minimum will always be 0.

Comment: Please re-read the code. The first `scanf` occurs outside the loop.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider OK yes.

Comment: @MrVeritas then follow one of the two suggested solutions.

Comment: Hey guys, @SurajJain's solution worked. I had to set those lines defining the `min` and `max` variables after the `scanf` function. Like this, `number` has been initialized and allows the `min`,`max` to be set to the first user value of `number`. Thanks to all you guys for the help!

Comment: @MrVeritas For them to see your comment please use their name `@name` `.

Comment: @SurajJain If they have eyeballs then can see my comment lol I was not referring to a single user but to all who have contributed to this post. So thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Line Of Your Code is wrong.

```
int min = number; //Lines 6 to 12 define the variables being used in this program.
int max = number;
```

As `number` is not initialised then , please instead put this after you input the number.

```
 printf("Please enter a value: ");
 scanf(" %d", &number);
 int min = number;        //Have These Lines Here
 int max = number;
```

Like One Of the Comments Tell You Changes Does Not Propagate , variables hold the value they are set to until changed later ,Changing `number` won't change the `min` and `max` automatically.

Comment: This worked thank you. Ive made other adjustments also to finalize this.

Comment: If you get above 15 points , please do not forget to upvote this. Were you in delusion that changes automatically propagate ?

Comment: In my programming class they stress that the order of your lines can be crucial to whether your program works the way its supposed to. That was the case here lol Now, I did *assume that my changes will propagate but only under the circumstances I have defined...not automatically.

Comment: @MrVeritas What circumstances , can you elaborate , and i said use their name , because , they wont get notification other wise .Why would they come on this question again , they should get notification for that you have to tag them , one at a time.